# how to declare an entity of type Object in avro schema

Tags: java, avro

My class:

```
public class User {

private Map<String, Object> field1;
private List<Object> field2;

}
```

Avro Schema for `List<Object>` throws exception:

```
{

"name": "field2",
"type": {
"type": "array"
"items":"string",
"java-class":"java.util.list"
}
}
```

similar exception for Map<String, Object>

Is there any other way that I can achieve this?
Is it not possible to use field of type "Object" in avro schema?

I did some research online, but could not find solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Avro has no generic type such as "Object", so if you're trying to store different types in the same container, then that's not possible

Note that your example is actually for `java.util.List<String>`